# Why do you have to parse the function call in a function during componentDidMount()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components, document

I was working through the state and lifecycle page on the react Doc. Why do I have to call a function within parsed function?

I tried removing the parsed function and just calling this.tick() but it did not work.

```
class Clock extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {date: new Date()};
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.timerID = setInterval(()=>this.tick(), 1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearInterval(this.timerID)
    }

    tick(){
        this.setState({
            date: new Date()
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
                <h1>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} </h1>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can do `setInterval(this.tick, 1000)` if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

because you need to pass the reference to the function to be executed, if you pass `this.tick()` that is a call to the function to be executed, you could to `this.tick` and that should work too

Comment: If you just pass `setInterval(this.tick, 1000)` , invocation context `this` will be lost, and it will not work. This is why you need to pass a fat-arrow function, which captures and preserves `this`.
`

Comment: @LogiGunaratnam When it comes to JS fundamentals, MDN is usually the place: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @IvanKoshelev you are right, my bad i forgot it was componentdidmount who is not arrow function so the this context is lost